# jQuery and jQueryUI new versions issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the latest jQuery UI version - 1.9.2 with jQuery 1.8.3 version. As several days ago, jQuery 1.9.0 version have come up, I have decided to try it, but got the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li role="presentation" 

class="ui-selectmenu-group ui-selectmenu-group-0"><span class="ui-selectmenu-group-label">

</span><ul></ul></li>
```

in

> jquery-1.9.0.min.js:2

file.

Has anyone know how to fix this or what is causing the issue?

Comment: What is the code that throws this error? And the snippet of HTML does not seem to be wellformed either.

Comment: Well, I am using jQuery UI tabs and my code is pretty big to past it - I am going to comment some code in order to find what is going wrong and past it then. But I did not get the error using 1.8.3 version ...

Comment: [work for me](http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/aJ9S9/)

Comment: try use unminified version and debugger to see call stack

Comment: I have found some "jquery.ui.selectmenu.performance.fix.js" include and commenting its functions do not trough the error. I am going to find who has added and if we can update it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was caused by "jQuery 1.9.0 and jQuery UI 1.10.0 Compatibility" of the select menu plugin.

In the next version of "jQuery UI" the plugin will be fully working with the latest "jQuery" and "jQuery UI" version.

Here you can find more details about select menu plugin compatibility: 
https://github.com/fnagel/jquery-ui/issues/286